# Sql Connection Error 40 Under Load

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

My database connections from my web servers work fine normally, but when a write heavy windows service I have triggers, I will randomly get "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Error 40." from my webservers.

I have tried turning connection pooling off for my web servers since they share the same connection string as the windows service, but I am at a loss as to what is still causing this.

My SqlConnection objects are all wrapped in using statements as well, so they are being disposed.

Dapper is being used currently for the query extension method.

Connection String example: "Data Source=SERVER;initial catalog=DBNAME;user id=USERNAME;password=PASSWORD;Pooling=False;"

```
using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
     return connection.Query<TotalPosts>("analytics.TotalPosts_Sel", new { AccountId = accountId }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: perhaps you should not use triggers how many triggers are you using..? do you have a DBA..? consult with the dba and try to debug the SQL..how are you sure that it's a sql issue could this be a network issue ??

Comment: I don't currently use any triggers. I thought it might be a network issue but it only happens when this windows service on a different machine is running. Sadly I don't have a DBA. I am hosted on AWS.

Comment: how are you making the connection via the different machines..? are these machines using the same Sql.DataClient that you use on the machines that are working..? what does the connection string look like.. are the connections being done via Linked Server..? sounds like a possible timeout issue as well it's really hard to determine what's going on here without knowing what you are doing or how you have done this..

Comment: This occurs when your connection is reset.  How often are you closing and opening your db connection?  Do you use the same db connection object for long periods of time?

Comment: do you have some code that shows how you are connecting in the service layer...?

Comment: I have added a code sample to the original post.

Comment: add it to your original question by editing your question

Comment: I might have solved it after running SQL Profiler and seeing 1 query was in bad need of indexes. I have added them and will continue to monitor my servers.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I realize this question is several years old, but as I hit the same problem in 2019 with .NET 4.8, I will post the problem, and a workaround.

Your problem is caused because of the speed you create and close connections and the number of connections that remain opened. You are causing a bottleneck in the low level database driver/library.

Some useful information to understand the problem:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/328476/description-of-tcp-ip-settings-that-you-may-have-to-adjust-when-sql-se

Using connection pooling can bring other issues as well:

http://florianreischl.blogspot.com/2011/08/adonet-connection-pooling-internals-and.html

My workaround was to sleep the thread for 20 ms. after each iteration. Dirty, but worked.

Regards,

MarianoC.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow those steps:

1- Make sure your SQL Server Service is started.

[image]

2- Make sure TCP/IP is enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager, Right-click TCP-IP, Go to Properties and make sure the default port is set to 1433.

[image]

3- Open your Windows Firewall. Click "Change Settings" link. When a new popup is shown, click "Add Port" button. Add 1433 as a TCP Port for SQL:

[image]

4- Connect to your SQL Connection in SSMS, Right-click and go to Properties. Then, make sure "Allow Remote Connections" checkbox is checked.

[image]

Reference: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/