# Error 40 and SqlAzureExecutionStrategy

Tags: azure-sql-database, entity-framework-core

I have a service fabric service (guest executable), using entityframework core, talking to sql azure.

From time to time I see the following error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection 
to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the 
instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

It *seems* transient as there are numerous database transactions that occur without errors. This seems to occur more when a node is busy.

I've added code in start up to set EnableRetryOnFailure to set the SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy:

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => 
            options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnection"),
            o => o.EnableRetryOnFailure()))
```

One major caveat, is at the moment I'm losing context so I don't know what data was attempting to be updated/inserted, so I don't know if it was eventually successful or not.

Couple of questions:

1. From the [Transient Detection Code](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/f386095005e46ea3aa4d677e4439cdac113dbfb1/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Storage/Internal/SqlServerTransientExceptionDetector.cs) it doesn't look like error: 40 is caught, but my understanding is that error 40 may actually be another error (unclear). Is that correct?
2. Is this really a transient issue or does it mean I have another problem?
3. Without additional logging (working on it), do we know if the retry strategy logs the error, but still retry's and in fact may have been successful?
4. If this is a transient error, but it's not caught in the default execution strategy, why not? and what would be unintentded consequences of sub classing the SqlAzureExecutionStrategy to include this error.

I've seen this question: [Sql Connection Error 40 Under Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746358/sql-connection-error-40-under-load), and it feels familiar, but he seems to have resolved it by tuning his database - which I will look at doing, I'm trying to make my code more resilient in the case of database issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a certain version of EF Core that caches the query or requests if the time span between two database transactions is very small, so update your packages to make sure you are using the most recent.
[Query: Threading issues cause NullReferenceException in SimpleNullableDependentKeyValueFactory #5456](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5456)

check these other links

1. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5456
2. https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/739
3. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6347
4. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4120